# Ask GDB to list all functions in a program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, x86-64

How can you list all functions in a program with GDB?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

`info functions` prints the names and data types of all defined functions. See [16 Examining the Symbol Table](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html).

Comment: And `info functions regexp` will list only functions with names matching the regexp. Documented in the same page.

Comment: Thank goodness for the regex, I'm trying to debug the Linux kernel :D

Comment: Just to be clear, the command is `info functions some_regex_here`, not `info functions regexp some_regex_here`. I was a bit confused for a moment