# Is there a way to automatically find which c++ namespace a method belongs to in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a huge code basis which several namespaces are scoped and unfortunately I miss which namespace my method is.

Does GDB helps me with that task if I just have a method name? Can it search through the namespaces to find my method?

e.g:

```
    (gdb) b getTranslation
    Function "getTranslation" not defined.
    Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
    (gdb) b HPHP::jit::getTranslation
    Function "HPHP::jit::getTranslation" not defined.
    Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
    (gdb) b HPHP::jit::MCGenerator::getTranslation
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x16a1a058: file hhvm/hphp/runtime/vm/jit/mc-generator.cpp, line 308.
    (gdb) # Ahhh, finally!
```

Normally I run through code and start collecting the namespaces, but sometimes they are tricky as a new namespace is defined in the middle of the header...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680670/ask-gdb-to-list-all-function-in-a-program) as hints, you might use e.g. `info functions getTranslation`, and it should list all functions named `getTranslation` complete with the classes/namespaces.